# Login Cake php utilizando otro modelo

Tags: cakephp, auth

Tengo en mi AppController la function initialize.

```
    public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' > [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Centros',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

El login me funciona bien para la tabla users pero tengo otro tabla donde tambien tengo el usuario y la contraseña que me gustaria que si el auth user falle compruebe el auth utilizando otro modelo, he intentado lo siguiente pero me devuelve false el auth . La funcion login la tengo dentro de mi UsersController.

```
public function login()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'Personas'),
                'Form' => array(
                   'fields' => [
                       'username' => 'usuario',
                       'password' => 'contraseña'
                   ],
                   'userModel' => 'Personas'
                   )
                );
            $monitor = $this->Auth->identify();
            if($monitor){
                $this->Auth->setUser($monitor);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```